# .htaccess redirect to HTTPS only within certain subfolder - if not, redirect to HTTP

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

Within my site I have a small shop. I'd like for .htaccess to redirect the user to HTTPS while in the shop URL, or any of its sub directories.

http://www.example.com/services/shop/ should redirect to HTTPS.

http://www.example.com/services/shop/view-products/ should redirect to HTTPS.

Whenever the user is NOT in the shop anymore, I'd like for the user to be redirected to HTTP.

https://www.example.com/services/ should redirect to HTTP.

https://www.example.com/ should redirect to HTTP.

https://www.example.com/company/about-us/ should redirect to HTTP.

How is this done in a clean and universal way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^services/shop/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^services/shop/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Looks good to me, but unfortunately when I enter the shop URL it redirects to HTTPS and then gives me the following message: "The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.". Also, when I am outside the shop and enter HTTPS myself, it stays in HTTPS.